# How to recieve files via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to transfer some pictures from my phone to my computer, but I cannot seem to find an option to receive files, only to send them. I tried looking up some guides for Ubuntu [(for example)](http://www.lorrin.org/blog/2015/01/08/receive-files-via-bluetooth-on-ubuntu/), but they all tell me to just enable a checkbox that isn't here on freya.

Is there a way to set it up manually, or an application that'll let me receive files over BT?

Comment: My answer on this question might help you out. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/how-do-i-accept-a-file-via-bluetooth/19472#19472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go into applications menu and search for **personal file sharing** there you will find an option called **receive files in downloads folder over bluetooth** tick that one...if you can't find it while searching, you can find it in **/usr/share/applications/** folder.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I couldn't find it by searching the applications popup.

Comment: that probably means the `.desktop` file has `NoDisplay=true` or/and `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;`, you can fix that by setting it to `NoDisplay=false` or/and  deleting `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;`.

Comment: What's the actual application name?