# Bluetooth issue

Tags: bluetooth, sharing

I have an issue with sharing option of bluetooth.
I can send files from my pc to my phone, but not form my phone to my pc.
My phone tell me that my pc don't accept any tranfered file.

I have configured this functionnality from System Panel > share > bluetooth but it doesn't work actually.

Sorry for my english !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Forgot to say : I use eOS 0.4 loki

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2390/how-to-recieve-files-via-bluetooth?rq=1

Comment: ty for your anwser.
But I've already done that and that doesn't work :/

Comment: EDIT : resolved by disable and enable again this option !