# How do I accept a file via Bluetooth?

Tags: pantheon, bluetooth

It's a bit strange to ask, but the situation is: I can easily send from my laptop with elementary OS files via Bluetooth, but I do not understand how to accept a file. The system notifies me that a device is trying to send me a file. I remember with ubuntu with GNOME it suffices to click "accept" to the notification itself, but on eOS any choiche does not appear and clicking on it leads to nothing. So: what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to fix this in elementaryOS 5 (Juno). You might be able to do this on lower versions as well:

1. Pair the device with your computer using the default Bluetooth settings in the control panel (I assume that you have already done this).
2. Install blueman: `sudo apt-get install blueman`
3. Open blueman services: `blueman-services`
4. A window should open, here you can select "Transfers" -> "Accept incoming files from trusted devices".

When you tick that box, it will work. I am not sure if you can remove blueman afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [Pieter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/13310/pieter-de-clercq) shared in his [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/19472/15156), I had to take the following additional steps before I could receive files from a Windows 10 laptop:

1. After installing blueman, restart the computer and open the applet (It might be possible to run the applet without restarting: `blueman-applet`).
2. Click on the applet icon and select "Devices...".
3. Select the Bluetooth device that you want to receive files from.
4. Make it trusted, either from the toolbar button, or from its context menu.

The crux is probably that blueman differentiates between trusted devices and connected but untrusted devices. It will automatically accept files only from trusted devices. It seems like there is no way to accept a file transfer from the gala notification, nor is there any way to mark a device as trusted except within blueman.

EDIT: I am on elementary OS 5.1 Hera, blueman 2.0.5-1ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

Im on Odin and tried to transfer files from my phone but unsuccessfully, just installed blueman and it work perfectly now ty